# I get a Channel Invalid error using telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I am trying to get Users from my Telegram Group to my other Telegram Group and using this code:

```
group_entity = InputPeerChannel(group.id, group.access_hash)
client(InviteToChannelRequest(channel=group_entity, users=[user_to_add]))
```

A few weeks before this code worked perfectly fine but now I get this error:
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.ChannelInvalidError: Invalid channel object. Make sure to pass the right types, for instance making sure that the request is designed for channels or otherwise look for a different one more suited (caused by InviteToChannelRequest)
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you must do like this:

```
group_entity = await client.get_entity(InputPeerChannel(group.id, group.access_hash))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).